# django view url mapping

Tags: python, django

I am trying to load a template from a nested directory in django but keep getting a improperly configured no pattern match error. I've attempted all combinations of folder names but the error keeps on continuing, I'm scratching my head with this one, any help? here are my files:

view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def index():
    curTemplate = loader.get_template('/droneMapper/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(curTemplate.render())
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.pardir)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')),)
```

the file strcture is:

```
root
 -app
 -templates
     -app
 -setting
```

Comment: Please post the actual error and full traceback. It seems unlikely to have anything to do with the code you have posted. Since you mention that it is a URL mapping error, don't you think you should perhaps have posted the urls.py?

Comment: Also, try loader.get_template('droneMapper/index.html') #slash removed

Answer (score 0):

I simply use this small code:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)
```

works fine for me.